# Unable to block YouTube using Tenda Router

Tags: networking, router, modem, youtube, url

In my office, we have more than 20 workstations and one server. All workstations have `Windows 7/Windows 8.1/Windows 10`. And our server OS in `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

We have broadband connection from `Airtel` to provide internet connectivity for all the above computers. We have an option to prevent access for some URL such as `www.facebook.com` and `www.youtube.com` from our service provider's modem (`Modem name: Tenda`) settings.

[image]

Currently, we have added above both URL in parental access on modem settings as image below. And, it restricts the access of the above both URL from all computers. But, we have an issue to access `www.google.com` when I try to restrict `YouTube`.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error do you get? "we have an issue to access www.google.com" isn't too clear :)

Comment: when we try to go to `www.google.com`, it seems blocked. same error shown if we go to `www.facebook.com` or `www.youtube.com`

Comment: That's not too detailed, but Google and Youtube are inextricably linked and use the same servers and domains often- that's something to consider.

Comment: @harley_woop So, How may I block only YouTube not Google?

Comment: I'm not sure on that- maybe try `https://www.youtube.*` to catch any subdomains

Comment: @harley_woop any way.. thanks! let me try. please share if you find any solution.